# How long is breast milk good out of the freezer?

Tags: safety, breastfeeding, bottle-feeding

I was breast feeding but I moved a few hours from were we lived and I had to stop because I had to drive 7 hours back and forth for a few days and didn't have the time to breastfeed or pump, so I froze a lot of milk.

After you take breast milk from the freezer, how long is it good for? I didn't warm it up, I just moved it from the freezer to the fridge, and I want to finish the one I have left but I'm not sure how to tell if it's good or not. How can I tell if the breast milk is bad?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE! Does this answer have the information you need? http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/18264/4054

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR; Go by the bacteria spoiling times, not the milk.

According to [this website](http://www.babycenter.com/404_how-long-does-breast-milk-stay-fresh_8918.bc),

> You can refrigerate breast milk for three to five days and freeze it to keep it fresh even longer. Thawed breast milk will keep in the refrigerator for up to 24 hours (but don't refreeze it). If you're traveling, you can store breast milk in an insulated cooler with ice packs for up to 24 hours.

It seems to expire quicker than other milk, due to the bacteria that can last for six to eight hours outside of refrigeration, 24 hours in normal refrigeration, and up to 2 weeks if in a colder area of the fridge. Keep in mind, the longer the milk stays in the fridge, the less time it will be viable at room temperature. See the below [chart and website](https://www.cdc.gov/breastfeeding/recommendations/handling_breastmilk.htm) for more detail.

[image]

**The largest thing to note is the good bacteria is what you're looking for, so going by the spoilage of the milk itself may not be a great determiner of whether it's good or not.**

Thanks to @gregmac for the chart from the CDC.